# Entries query by Super Table field

Tags: craft3, plugin-supertable

I have a section with a [Super Table](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/super-table/features) field, each "row" of which contains a date field. I am looking for a way to query for entries where one of the rows contains a future date.

Comment: The solution of the previous comment did workout for me, just notice that the blocks should be called like this: stc_XXX field_XXX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically the same as [Find entries that use a specific block in their Matrix field?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/27297/5557)

You can use the base query and left join your Super Table content row

```twig
{% set entries = craft
    .entries()
    .section(['your-section'])
    .leftJoin('{{%supertableblocks}} as supertableblocks', '[[supertableblocks.ownerId]] = [[entries.id]]')
    .leftJoin('{{%stc_content}} as stc_content', '[[stc_content.elementId]] = [[supertableblocks.id]]')
    .andWhere(['>=', 'stc_content.field_date', entry.date|date('atom')]) 
    .groupBy('supertableblocks.ownerId')
    .all()
%}
```

Note: this is untested, maybe you need certain modifications it should just be some kind of guidance. Please keep in mind to replace your actual table and field names. I just used `stc_content` as a demonstration as well as `stc_content.field_date`

Comment: great thank you, I had not seen the tables created by the plugin.
Thanks it works now

Comment: I get a SQL error when setting `groupBy` that says it's incompatible with MySql 5.7's `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` setting. Any way to modify to avoid the error?