# Query on Super Table field's entry field

Tags: craft3, plugin-supertable

I have a section with a Super Table field that has an entry field. 
Now I want to find the entries that have a relation to that entry.

I found this answer here. This but I can not get it to work with the entry field type.

[query on Super Table field's date field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/27345/query-on-super-table-fields-date-field)

Thank you for your help

```
 $events = Entry::find()
        ->section('foo')
        ->leftJoin('supertableblocks', 'supertableblocks.ownerId = entries.id')
        ->leftJoin('stc_foo', 'stc_foo.elementId = supertableblocks.id')
        ->groupBy('supertableblocks.ownerId')
        ->where(I don't know what to do here with the entry field)
        ->all();
```