# Query entries with latest video field containing a URL

Tags: search, query

I would like to set up a query to find the latest news article that has a video attached to it ('video' is a matrix field with a block type that is also called 'video' and a field called 'videoUrl').

I know I can use the following query, but I get stuck defining searchQuery. Or is there another method?

{% set results = craft.entries()
.search(searchQuery)
.one() %}

Comment: There seems to be a similar question/answer over here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/27297/526 that should put you on the right path!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
No need to use search in this case.

{% set results = craft.entries.videoField(':notempty:').orderBy('postDate desc').one() %}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!